# detect events of overlapping signals from two columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns A and B.  The values in A and B can be either 0.0 or 1.0 (binary state).

The signals are most of the time all 0.0, with occasional 1.00.  I want to detect each event whereby both A and B are 1.00 and overlapping (inner join).

Here's a sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
%matplotlib inline
np.random.seed(101)

data = np.zeros((1200,2),dtype=float)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-05-19', 
                  freq='50ms', periods=1200),
                  columns=['A','B'])
#event1
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:01.000'):pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:02.500'),'A'] =1.00
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:01.500'):pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:03.000'),'B'] =1.00
#event2
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:12.000'):pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:15.000'),'A'] =1.00
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:13.000'):pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:14.500'),'B'] =1.00
#event3
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:40.000'):pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:43.000'),'A'] =1.00
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:42.000'):pd.to_datetime('2020-05-19 00:00:46.000'),'B'] =1.00
```

Line plot of A and B to visualize the overlaps.  Note I have shifted A by 0.01 to make all the lines visible.

```
def plot_Class_AB():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,figsize=(15,4))
    ax.set_title("Checking overlaps of A and B")

    ax.plot(df['A'].dropna()+0.01,label="A",color='red')
    ax.plot(df['B'].dropna(),label="B",color='blue')
    ax.set_ylabel("Class")
    ax.legend()
```

[image: Line plot of A and B signals]

I can manage to get the start time of the first event, and the end time of the very last event as follows.

```
events_startTime = df[(df['A'] == 1.00)  & (df['B'] == 1.00)].head(1).index
events_endTime   = df[(df['A'] == 1.00)  & (df['B'] == 1.00)].tail(1).index
print('events_startTime:',events_startTime)
print('events_endTime:  ',events_endTime)
```

However I'm interested in the timings of the individual events overlaps.  My expected output is something similar to this:

```
event1_startTime = 2020-05-19 00:00:01.500
event1_endTime:  = 2020-05-19 00:00:02.500

event2_startTime = 2020-05-19 00:00:13.000
event2_endTime:  = 2020-05-19 00:00:14.500

event3_startTime = 2020-05-19 00:00:42.000
event3_endTime:  = 2020-05-19 00:00:43.000
```

Can you suggest any idea how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What about multiplying the two signals and find the indexes where the product is non zero?

```
import numpy as np

a = df['A'].dropna().values
b = df['B'].dropna().values

events_idxs = np.where(a*b > 0.5)[0]
```

(I put a 0.5 threshold because it looks like your signals are not exactly 0 outside the events)

Answer (score 1):

Create filter for high signal:

```
events_on_filter = (df['A'] == 1.00)  & (df['B'] == 1.00)
```

Apply filter ad get only True

```
events_on = events_on_filter[events_on_filter==True]
df[['A', 'B']].diff().plot(figsize=(15,10))
```

[image]

Get signal front:

```
s_up = df[['A', 'B']].diff()==1
s_down = df[['A', 'B']].diff()==-1
```

Take the index of both signals for both rising and falling edges

```
idx_a_up = s_up['A'][d['A']==True].index
idx_b_up = s_up['B'][d['B']==True].index
idx_a_down = s_down['A'][s_down['A']==True].index
idx_b_down = s_down['B'][s_down['B']==True].index
```

Iterate over index to get the individual events overlaps

```
for start1, start2, end1, end2 in zip(idx_a_up, idx_b_up, idx_a_down, 
   idx_b_down):
   if start1 < start2:
       event1_startTime = df.loc[start2]
   else:
       event1_startTime = df.loc[start1]
   if end1 > end2:
       event1_endTime = df.loc[end2]
   else:
       event1_endTime = df.loc[end1]
    
   print(f'event1_startTime: {event1_startTime.name} - event1_endTime: 
   {event1_endTime.name}' )
```

Output:

event1_startTime: 2020-05-19 00:00:01.500000 - event1_endTime: 2020-05-19 00:00:02.550000

event1_startTime: 2020-05-19 00:00:13 - event1_endTime: 2020-05-19 00:00:14.550000

event1_startTime: 2020-05-19 00:00:42 - event1_endTime: 2020-05-19 00:00:43.050000

Answer (score 0):

I used JacoSolari's suggestion which returns a list of all indices where A == B ==1.00.  For the above example it returns the following array:

```
array([ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,
        43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264,
       265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277,
       278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290,
       840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852,
       853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860], dtype=int64)
```

Eventually I added the below function that extracts a list of start and stop indices of all events from the above array.  Code below.

```
def find_start_stop_indexes(df):

    a = df['A'].dropna().values
    b = df['B'].dropna().values

    events_idxs = np.where(a*b > 0.5)[0]

    if len(events_idxs) > 0:

        # initiate a list to store first,last index of each event
        first_last = [events_idxs[0]]
        i = 1
        while i < len(events_idxs):
            if (events_idxs[i] - events_idxs[i-1]) < 2:   
                i = i+1
                if i == len(events_idxs):
                    first_last.append(events_idxs[i-1])
            else:
                first_last.append(events_idxs[i-1])
                first_last.append(events_idxs[i])
                i = i +1
                if i == len(events_idxs):
                    first_last.append(events_idxs[i-1])

        return(first_last)
    else:
        return([])
```

The output of the function for the above example is:

```
[30, 50, 260, 290, 840, 860]
```

Not sure if there's an easier solution, but it works.